# How to select specific records from SQL Table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I'm in a SQL class right and I'm meant to do this: List the first name, last name and phone number for all students that registered on 2/13/2007. Arrange the list in order of last name and first name.

Right now I am trying this SQL Statement. I get a "no rows selected" notification when I run this:

```
Select first_name, last_name, phone
FROM Student
WHERE registration_date LIKE '%13/02/2007%'
ORDER by last_name, first_name;
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been on this for about a half hour now.

Comment: LIKE doesn't work for dates. You're not looking for a date that's LIKE anything, anyway. You're looking for a date that equals a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on *default* date format nor Oracle's capabilities of implicit conversion from a string to a DATE. Either use DATE literal (which always has the same format: YYYY-MM-DD), or use TO_DATE function with appropriate format mask.

```
select first_name, last_name, phone
from student
where registration_date = date '2007-02-13'
order by last_name, first_name;
```

or

```
select first_name, last_name, phone
from student
where registration_date = to_date('13.02.2007', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
order by last_name, first_name;
```

If such a query still doesn't return anything, maybe REGISTRATION_DATE contains a time component (I presume it shouldn't, but you can never know). You'd then have to remove it, such as

```
where trunc(registration_date) = date '2007-02-13'
```

and that will cause index on that column *unusable*, unless you create a function-based index.

Another possibility is that there's noone who registered on 13.02.2007.

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the table structure ? 
command desc tablename and why are you putting like condition when you want to execute for a particular registration date.

*Depending on the information given in question*

`SELECT first_name, last_name, phone FROM student WHERE registration_date='2008-11-11' ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name DESC`

Use like this.